# how to get specific nodes which has specific attribute in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I want to find the nodes which has a specific attribute (like in example below we have attribute attr )

```
<root>
  <anynode id="1" attr="abc">
    first node
  </anynode>
  <anynode id="2">
    2nd node
  </anynode>
  <anynode id="3" attr="abc">
    3rd node
  </anynode>
  <anynode id="4" attr="def">
    4th node
  </anynode>
</root>
```

and i want it to traverse with XMLDocument and XDocument both 
and if i can get value of ID and ATTR in one ittration that would be great 
i have googled little bit but i didnt find any path which can help me lead to 
final result i want

```
1,abc , first node
3,abc , 3rd node
4,def , 4th node
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Using the System.Xml.Linq namespace we can take advantage of the XDocument class to find the "id" and "attr" attributes of the "anynode" element.

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"path to xml file");

var nodes = xmlDocument.Element("root")?.Elements("anynode");
if (nodes == null)
    return;
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    var id = node.Attribute("id")?.Value;
    var attr = node.Attribute("attr")?.Value;
    Console.WriteLine($"ID = {id}, ATTR  = {attr}");
}
```